# Where is the bitcoin automatic address generation?

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, privacy, random

I have head of the automatic bitcoin address generation feature for every transaction. I have done multiple transaction, but I still have the same addresses (I have two addresses). I would like to enable the automatic address generation feature. Where is it? I am using the original bitcoin-qt client.

Comment: I'm not sure if the Satoshi (Qt) client has that feature for receiving addresses. But I thought it at least always makes new addresses for change...

Comment: It's about how you use it: every time you give an address to someone to receive a transaction, ask for a new address.

Answer (score 1):

The standard Bitcoin software up to version 0.4.x had a GUI based on wxWidgets rather than QT. For version 0.5 it was merged with the then-separate bitcoin-qt.

The older version allowed you to select an address to be displayed in the overview. If you received funds to an address while it is selected, Bitcoin would automatically generate a new address.

I don't believe this functionality still exists in the QT version. It does however still generate new addresses for change.